# Create form and input field through javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing my javascript assignment in which I have a form and there are multiple buttons in it. I want that javascript should render like

```
<form>
<input />
<button />
</form>
```

but it is rendering like this

```
 <form> </form>
    <input />
    <button />
```

sample code

```
var formTag = document.createElement('form');
document.body.appendChild(formTag);
var txtInput = document.createElement("input");
var txtNode = document.createTextNode("0");
txtInput.setAttribute("id", "txtInput");
txtInput.appendChild(txtNode);
document.form.appendChild(txtInput);
```

Comment: becoz jquery and javascript community is interlinked.

Comment: Billz, @j08691 is implying the post should be tagged based on its content and semantics, not ratings considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistakenly appending the `input` element to the document's `form` element (which, by the way, does not exist - you probably meant [`document.forms[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.forms)).

Append the input to the `formTag` object instead, like so:

```
formTag.appendChild(txtInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try appending the txtInput to your formTag object instead..

```
var formTag = document.createElement('form');
document.body.appendChild(formTag);
var txtInput = document.createElement("input");
var txtNode = document.createTextNode("0");
txtInput.setAttribute("id", "txtInput");
txtInput.appendChild(txtNode);
formTag.appendChild(txtInput);
```